# Applying a function returned from a subparser with fparsec

Tags: f#, fparsec

Noob alert!

Ok, I'm trying to build a simple math expression parser in fparsec. Right now all I want it to do is handle strings like this "1+2-3*4/5" and return a double as the result of the evaluation. No spaces, newlines, or parens, and left to right order of operations is fine.

Here's what I have so far:

```
let number = many1 digit |>> fun ds -> int <| String.Concat(ds)

let op : Parser<int -> int -> int, unit> =
    charReturn '+' (+) <|>
    charReturn '-' (-) <|>
    charReturn '*' (*) <|>
    charReturn '/' (/)

let expression, expressionImpl = createParserForwardedToRef()
do expressionImpl :=
    choice[
        attempt(number .>> op >>. expression);
        number]

let test p str =
    match run (p .>> eof) str with
    | Success(result, _, _) -> printfn "Success: %A" result
    | Failure(result, _, _) -> printfn "Failure: %A" result

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    test expression "1+1/2*3-4"
    Console.Read() |> ignore

    0
```

In the first choice of the expression parser, I'm not sure how to apply the function returned by the op parser.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, I find the answer right after posting the question (after 3 hours of searching).

I just changed this line:

```
attempt(number .>> op >>. expression);
```

to this:

```
attempt(pipe3 number op expression (fun x y z -> y x z));
```

However, I just realized that my expressions parse backwards. Back to the drawing board.